# Why does my custom adminhtml form select element have two options selected?

Tags: magento-1, adminhtml, adminform, bug

I have a custom form in my module (in admin). It has a select, whose default value should be "*", but instead, it has both "*" and "0" selected:

```
<select id="customer_group_id" name="customer_group_id" title="Customer Group" class=" select">
    <option value="*" selected="selected">ANY</option>
    <option value="0" selected="selected">NOT LOGGED IN</option>
    <option value="1">General</option>
    <option value="2">Wholesale</option>
    <option value="3">Retailer</option>
    <option value="4">Partners</option>
</select>
```

The field is being added to the form with this code:

```
$fieldset->addField('customer_group_id', 'select', array(
    'name'   => 'customer_group_id',
    'label'  => 'Customer Group',
    'title'  => 'Customer Group',
    'values' => $helper->getAvailableCustomerGroups(),
    'value'  => '*'
));
```

It gets its values from a function in my helper class. This function simply grabs all of the customer groups in the store, and also adds the "*" option.

```
function getAvailableCustomerGroups() {
    return array_merge(
        array('*'=>'ANY'),
        Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')->toOptionHash()
    );

}
```

**Why does the form have TWO options marked SELECTED?**

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug deep within the `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Select` class. I was able to track it down by adding this debugging code to [the `_toOptionHtml()` function in `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Select`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Select.php#L94):

```
if (in_array($option['value'], $selected)) {
    $type = gettype($option['value']);
    Mage::log("Marking option ($type){$option['value']} as SELECTED because it is in the values array.");
    Mage::log($selected);

    $html.= ' selected="selected"';
}
```

This gives me a log like:

```
DEBUG (7): Element name: customer_group_id  Element value: *
DEBUG (7): Marking option (string)* as SELECTED because it is in the values array.
DEBUG (7): Array (
    [0] => *
)

DEBUG (7): Marking option (integer)0 as SELECTED because it is in the values array.
DEBUG (7): Array (
    [0] => *
)
```

I can now see what is happening; the "NOT LOGGED IN" group has a value of `(integer)0`, and not `(string)0`. This is a well known "got'cha" with the `in_array` function, as explained in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13846839/884734

This makes sense, because `toOptionHash()` would return a `key=>value` type structure, and it's an (int) column in the database, so logically php must use (integer) for the index.

An easy work-around to this bug is to change `getAvailableCustomerGroups()` function to return an `optionArray` and not an `optionHash`. Here is the fixed helper code:

```
function getAvailableCustomerGroups() {
    return array_merge(
        array(
            array( 'value' => '*', 'label' => 'ANY' )
        ),
        Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')->toOptionArray()
    );
}
```

As for fixing the underlying bug, hopefully the core devs will.